# Can I use metal studs for framing a shed?

Tags: studs

We're building a shed on a pontoon so it will float.  Therefore we need it to be light weight yet sturdy enough to hold up to snow in the winter.  Will metal studs provide enough strength and support for this project?

Comment: Metal studs are available in different gauges

Comment: An [*A-frame* building](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-frame_house) is well suited to standing up to heavy snow, and requires less structural strength as a result of its design.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes.

<sup><sub>*But I have to have at least 30 characters to submit an answer.*</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

Going beyond 'can' to 'should' will involve asking:

- How long a service life is desired from the shed? This will determine the grade of framing to be used.
- What type of water (fresh or salt)?
- What amount of buoyancy will be available (weight capacity for shed and contents)?
- How tall a structure?  Have you considered the 'sail effect' of a rigid structure?

You might look at [temporary or permanent carport structures](http://www.teksupply.com/contractor/supplies/prod1;ts_buildings_storage-ts_vehicle_garages_carports;pgpb01900r4n.html):

For example, the pictured structure has:

> • Frame is 17 gauge, 1.315" OD USA-made, triple-galvanized structural steel tubing. • 12.5 oz., 24 mil premium forest green cover comes with a 15 year warranty. • 4'W white skylight.

It has a good snow rating, but snow must be removed manually.

> How much snow can my building withstand?
>   TekSupply structures are very sturdy and capable of withstanding winter months in high snowfall areas. Most snow easily slides off the cover's smooth surface. In the event of buildup, the snow can be easily removed by tapping on the building's ceiling from the inside. For additional safety, most of our buildings are available for purchase with additional rafters. Rafter spacing can be increased from every 4' to every 3' for an additional cost.

[image]